# Nvidia GPU not supported by driver 510 on Debian testing

Tags: debian, nvidia

I have an old **Nvidia GeForce GTX 760 card** on my desktop (Debian testing/amd64).

```
$ lspci -nn | egrep -i "3d|display|vga"
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 760] [10de:1187] (rev a1)
```

This card is supported by **Nvidia driver version 470**. I'm currently using `nvidia-driver` package version 470.141.03-2

```
$ dpkg -l nvidia-driver*|grep ^ii
ii  nvidia-driver                470.141.03-2 amd64        NVIDIA metapackage
ii  nvidia-driver-bin            470.141.03-2 amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  nvidia-driver-libs:amd64     470.141.03-2 amd64        NVIDIA metapackage (OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES libraries)
```

On Debian testing (bookworm), `nvidia-driver` was recently updated to version 510.85.02 => https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/nvidia-graphics-drivers

My old Nvidia GeForce GTX 760 card is not supported by Nvidia driver version 510. When I try to update my packages, I have an error message (end of support with driver v510) :

```
nvidia-graphics-drivers (495.44-1) experimental; urgency=medium

    LEGACY GPUs: If you have a GRID K520, GeForce 710A,
    GeForce 710M/810M/820M/825M/910M/920M, GeForce GT 630/635/640/640M/645M,
    GeForce GT 650M/710/720/720M/730/730M/730M/740/740M/745M/750M/755M,
    GeForce GTX 645/650/660/660M/670/670MX/675MX/680/680M/680MX/690/760/760M,
    GeForce GTX 765M/770/770M/775M/780/780M/860M/870M/880M,
    GeForce GTX TITAN/TITAN Black/TITAN Z, NVS 510, Quadro 410/K420/K500M/K510M,
    Quadro K600/K610M/K1000M/K1100M/K2000/K2000D/K2000M/K2100M/K3000M/K3100M,
    Quadro K4000/K4000M/K4100M/K4200/K5000/K5000M/K5100M/K5200/K6000,
    Tesla K8/K10/K20/K40/K80, i.e., any GPU based on the
    GK104/GK104GL/GK104M/GK104GLM, GK106/GK106GL/GK106M/GK106GLM,
    GK107/GK107GL/GK107M/GK107GLM, GK110/GK110B/GK110BGL/GK110GL, GK180GL,
    GK208/GK208B/GK208BM/GK208M/GK208GLM, GK210GL chips or a variant thereof
    (that is anything from the Kepler architecture),
    DO NOT INSTALL THIS RELEASE!!!
    Use the nvidia-tesla-470-driver, nvidia-tesla-470-kernel-dkms
    packages instead.
```

I stopped the Debian update to prevent installation of `nvidia-driver` package v510.

To continue to use my Nvidia card, I need to use `nvidia-tesla-470-driver` package instead of `nvidia-driver` package (updated to version 510).

**But how to migrate from `nvidia-driver` to `nvidia-tesla-470-driver` without breaking my Debian distribution ?**

Comment: You can mark `nvidia-driver` and all nvidia packages it depends on as "held" with `apt-mark hold [package-names]` (FYI, I do this routinely with nvidia drivers - in fact, all dkms packages, and a handful of other packages too.  I don't want stuff like that updating without me explicitly doing it).   Or just `apt-get install nvidia-tesla-470-driver` - I had to switch to legacy drivers on a machine with a 560 Ti card several years ago and the transition was smooth and error-free.  It Just Worked without a problem.  I expect that this would still be true now.

Comment: Oddly, unlike the 760, the GTX 750 installed in my Debian Sid mythtv box is still supported.  I've been expecting it to be relegated to the legacy driver for some time now but it's still listed as supported in `/usr/share/doc/nvidia-driver/README.txt.gz` for 510.85.02. Not for much longer, I guess.

Comment: FYI, now might be a good time to look around for a cheap GTX 1060 or AMD RX 570 or something.  The GPU cash-grab "arbitrage is just a prettier name for scalping, so some scumbags can pretend they're not scumbags" crisis of the last few years is going away (largely because the "crypto"-"coin" idiots are no longer very interested in GPUs).  I'm planning to get an RX 6600 or similar soon (just waiting to see if the RX 7600 is going to be reasonably priced. If not, I'll get a 6600), and my current 1060 can go into my myth box to replace the 750.

Comment: Thanks @cas, I have uninstalled `nvidia-driver` packages and depends, then install `nvidia-tesla-470-driver` packages and depends. After reboot, my old GPU card is well recognized by Nvidia Tesla 470 driver and audio/video works well. And you're right : it's time to look for a cheap GTX 1060/1080 to replace my old card ; I don't need a super recent GPU card because I don't use it to play or doing 3D stuff on Linux.